# PDO Exceptions could not find driver

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

PDO Exceptions could not find driver

here is my function

```
class Database extends PDO {

public function __construct() {
    try{
    parent::__construct(DB_TYPE . ':host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . $DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
    } catch (Exception $e){
        echo '<pre>';
        echo 'Message:' .$e->getMessage().'<br>';
        echo 'Message:' .$e->getTraceAsString().'<br>';
        print_r(get_loaded_extensions());
        echo '</pre>';
    }
```

}

and I am getting

could not find a driver

> 0 /home/dltechi/public_html/dating/libs/Database.php(11):
>   PDO->__construct('DB_TYPE:host=DB...', 'DB_USER', 'DB_PASS')   1
>   /home/dltechi/public_html/dating/libs/Model.php(6):
>   Database->__construct('DB_TYPE', 'DB_HOST', 'DB_NAME', 'DB_USER',
>   'DB_PASS') 2 /home/dltechi/public_html/dating/libs/Controller.php(22):
>   Model->__construct()   3
>   /home/dltechi/public_html/dating/libs/Bootstrap.php(103):
>   Controller->useModel('test', 'models/')  4
>   /home/dltechi/public_html/dating/libs/Bootstrap.php(30):

```
 Bootstrap->_loadExistingController()
5 /home/dltechi/public_html/dating/index.php(83): Bootstrap->init()
6 {main}
```

Comment: What's the contents of `$DB_TYPE` ?

Comment: I defined them in separate file  here it is
define('DB_TYPE', 'mysql'); 
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', 'dating');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASS', '');

Comment: Show us your full class with full exception and stack trace.

Comment: I just add up there is the class of database in local host its working fine but online not working, I have checked enabled extensions. still getting errors here is the link [link] (http://dltech.info/dating/test/)

Comment: Are you including the file you defined them in?

Comment: yes, I am working on a MVC framework and yes I did. in local its working fine but online driver missing.

Answer (score 0):

I am using laragon FOR LARAVEL and was facing same problem but i figured it out...And My php version is 7.2
For the older versions uncomment the php_pdo_mysql & mysql.dll (make sure u are using pgsql/pgmysqllite or any other and uncomment them and for non used ones you have to use';'

CHECK THE PATH IN ENVVIRONMENT VARIABLES. and version >7

undo all the extensions in php.ini except for THE

extension=pdo_mysql

Because the latest versions are encoded without the 'php_pdo_mysql & other .dll' files & are already i compiled i guess. ESPECIALLYY FOR THE {{PDO_****}} disable them & enable above code..and ';'

With doing that u can change your utf8mbg to utf8 respecitvely to both charset and collation:

inside app\config\database.php set the default to 'mysql'.

------>>app\config\database.php & set the default to 'mysql'

'mysql' => [ **** others are same just change the following]

```
'charset' => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
```